# Python crashes when reading U16 and U8 PCIDSK layers to numpy arrays with GDAL

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, gdal

The [PCIDSK](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_pcidsk.html) (normally .pix) format allows for bands with multiple data types to be held in the same file. My files contain "U16", "U8" and "BIT" channels.

GDAL is able to interpret the dataset correctly:

```
ds = gdal.Open("myfile.pix") 
    for i in range(1,ds.RasterCount+1):     
        print ds.GetRasterBand(i).DataType, ds.GetRasterBand(i).GetDescription()
```

It is interpreting the "U16" band as `gdalconst.GDT_UInt16` (2), and the "U8" and "BIT" as `gdalconst.GDT_Byte` (1). I can see all the bands from the original file, in the correct order, with proper band names.

The problem is when I try to extract the data to numpy arrays. pythonw.exe crashes (not even an error in the console) when I try the usual `ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()`.

I noticed that I was able to extract some data correctly by specifying the region to extract but it still crashing when the region includes one specific pixel, which is different from file to file. The given pixel is problematic for all "U16" and "U8" layers.

For a file 9494 (X) x 9609 (Y), it fails only at:

```
ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(8704,9472,1,1)
```

For a file 9193 (X) x 9293 (Y), it fails only at:

```
ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray(5376,9216,1,1)
```

There is nothing notable about the pixels in the original data. I noticed that the unreadable locations would be located at edge of a tile 256x256 tile interleaved in the original.

It seems to be able to handle the "BIT" layers correctly with .ReadAsArray(), but not the "U16" and "U8".

The machine has plenty of memory, and I able to read and create other datasets that are much larger.

As a side note, if any knows how to create PCIDSK files with multiple data types, it would be useful for me to create a working example of the problem.

Using Python 2.7.11, Numpy 1.10.2, gdal bindings 1.11.3.

Comment: I apologize for the multiple edits; I'm trying to refine my description of the issue...

Comment: Interestingly, the gdal_translate utility also bombs on the command line when attempting to convert to GeoTiff, but also when converting the single band to another PCIDSK file...